# Instagram OAuth Login returning "Matching code was not found or was already used"

Tags: instagram, omniauth, oauth-2.0

So I have a web app that login to Instagram. Works fine for months. No code changes, and suddenly I'm getting

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used."}
```

Logging out of instagram.com on my browser and using my web app to login with instagram oauth.... now it works. And it works repeatedly (logging in and out of my app with instagram oauth). Works fine.

Until I access a www.instagram.com webpage on my browser. Then my oauth login fails again with the same error. And I can't login to my web app with instagram oauth again until I logout of instagram.com itself

Comment: im also seeing the same error, with a different situation. I tend to believe it might be an instagram internal issue. I also noticed that some of my test users cannot access their "manage applications" section. https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/. the page returns 500 internal server error...

Comment: Hello. This happens for me only when I refresh the page after I've been logged in. Any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: Please check this simple [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59159954/1576416) if you are following the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem happening here: [Instagram returning "Matching code was not found or was already used" when using OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263821/instagram-returning-matching-code-was-not-found-or-was-already-used-when-using/38274456#38274456)

Seems like it's on Instagram's end.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.

I clear the browser cache and I logout from Instagram.
And I try OAuth login again, I can login now (it returns normal response).

It may not be the perfect solution. Please try it.

Comment: doesn't reliably work for me. But retrying the oauth login a bunch of times eventually leads to success.

Answer (score 0):

I send the HTTP request through SOCKS proxy and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows because Access_Token is generated and we are trying to re-generate with same 'CODE'. If you want new ACCESS_TOKEN then you need to re-generate the code and use that CODE to generate the ACCESS_TOKEN.

Here is the sample URL to generate CODE.

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-CODE&redirect_uri=REQUEST-URI&response_type=code&scope=public_content

client_id = Client ID from Instagram

redirect_uri = The URL which you have added for permission on Instagram

scope = To set the permission for new generating CODE.