# Instagram returning "Matching code was not found or was already used" when using OAuth

Tags: oauth, instagram

I am trying to use the **Instagram OAuth** using the developer documentation at

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/.

Step 1 and 2 are working without any problems, so I have my `Client-ID`, the `Client-Secret`, the `Redirect-URI` and the code.

But every-time I am trying to get the `Acces Token` I get the following error:

```
{
"code": 400, 
"error_type": "OAuthException", 
"error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used."
}
```

Any tips how to solve this?

Comment: We're experiencing the same thing on some of our production servers at the moment. Working perfectly fine locally though.

Comment: I have been receiving this message all day on my development machine.

Comment: I following @miguelpelota instruction and do the trick from Ravi-Misra by clearing browser (I open new incognito window). That work for me.

Comment: I've been seeing this issue in my server logs since a few days

Comment: Seems to be a big issue with Instagram these days. Unsure what to do.

Comment: I posted a solution to the problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210164/instagram-api-matching-code-was-not-found-or-was-already-used/41244875

Comment: We too facing this issue from yesterday but it is intermittent, same account sometime able to configure but fail other time

Comment: Please check this simple [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59159954/1576416) if you are following the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are experiencing the same issue.  It appears that logging out of Instagram, then attempting to use Instagram OAuth through our site after we are logged out of Instagram is a workaround.

Comment: Great, that did the trick! I logged out of instagram and did Step 1. While doing that, I had to loggin again. But with this trick I finally got step 3 working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: that did the job.... after wasting hours of searching the web that solved it. Just log out and login via the api. It seems that you have to store the code for the user though? In that case that error message seems a little bit twisted for me.

Comment: I don't think logging out fixes the problem. I have the same problem in a production environment. It works for some users and it does not for some others.

Comment: It does not work for me. I get error: 400 with message `Matching code was not found or was already used` when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 6):

We're experiencing the same issue since yesterday (after months of working fine) - have reported it as an issue yesterday via the 'Report Issue' function on https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ and I'd encourage you to do the same.

Yet to hear back, but seems likely it's their end having issues rather than something we're doing.

EDIT: It's also working fine for us on our development servers (which use different IPs for interacting with IG's API) but not working on our production server from any of the IPs we have available on the production server.

EDIT2: (July 2016) Just tested and it's mysteriously started working again on our production servers. No reply to the support ticket from Instagram as yet.

EDIT3: (December 2016) And now it's failing again with the same message... Seems like it's Instagram's end again. Nothing much we can do. Frustrating.

Comment: Great - I also linked to the thread in my report. Seems widespread to me - I just tried using Woobox (popular Facebook page plugin) and their Instagram integration wasn't working either.

Comment: I also already wrote them days ago and haven't heard back anything since...

Comment: Just tested and it's mysteriously started working again on our production servers. No reply to the support ticket from Instagram as yet.

Comment: And now it's failing again with the same message... Seems like it's Instagram's end again. Nothing much we can do. Frustrating.

Comment: Seems like some accounts are fine and others aren't. I was able to authenticate with one sandbox account, but then the creator gets the error message... Then it almost worked where it would give me the token, but then the token was immediately invalid. Tried completely revoking the apps access, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ahamilton9 yes - and it's intermittent and random too - throughout the day it's sometimes working for some users and sometimes throwing this error. Not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Logging in to Instagram, then complete Step 1 from the API Docs (`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code`), then follow the redirect and copying the code from the URL, then logging out of my account, then completing Step 3:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

We are also experiencing the same issue from yesterday, looks like clearing browser (or new incognito window) do the trick. Although, the mobile app where we are authenticating through mobile browser, working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Deleted all my browsing history, cleared cache, etc. Like it was a brand new browser and now it works with no issue.

I've been hammering on the auth URL for weeks now. Testing and using the same stored token to re-authorize. Maybe stored tokens have a limit to the number of times they can be re-used?

======

Having the same issue as of today. Authorization was working fine earlier - now I'm getting the same 'Matching code...' response.

Signed in and out of my Instagram account repeatedly, created a new app id and disabled/enabled Implicit Oauth - all with no success.

The 'Authorized Applications' view in my Instagram account reports that my application has indeed been authorized, but I can't make calls to the API. Authenticating through an Incognito window returned a successful response but it's not a solution.

Tried reporting to Instagram through their 'Report Issue' form, but it won't allow me to submit the form.

Comment: We are also experiencing the same issue from yesterday, When we clear browser cache or used other browser first time it worked but when try again it fail so its not full proof solution but definitely temporary solution. I have also raised the issue

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message. After 2 hours trying every workaround, I realized that I was using FB secret code instead of IG. Double check it first before trying any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Just log out of Instagram and try again. That worked for me.

Comment: Neither for me...has anyone found an explanation or solution for this. None, of the answers from this thread worked for me.

Comment: @lonut i added my solution above. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a service on the backend/server side that authorised the user.

My backend API is a ruby on rails app. Here is a code snippet to understand.

```
  def token
    @response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], redirect_uri: mobile_token_url)
    instagram_user = InstagramUserCreator.new(user_params)
    if instagram_user.find_or_create
      redirect_to "taddarmobileapp://?token=#{instagram_user.user.token}"
    else
      redirect_to 'taddarmobileapp://'
    end
  end
```

I just store the token on the phone and use it to authorise the user to my backend API.