# Instagram oauth api gives {"error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used.", "code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException"}

Tags: api, instagram

I am seeing this error from my live server using the Instagram API.

```
{
"error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used."
, "code": 400
, "error_type": "OAuthException"
}
```

I have read a few suggestion on here to clear cache but that isn't fixing the issue. I am also unable to submit a support ticket directly on the Instagram site as I am receiving an error message while attempting to submit a ticket.

Comment: I also didn't figure why this happens. But in my case, if I go to http://www.instagram.com and logout from there and try again it works.

Comment: Please checkout this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163518/instagram-oauth-error-400-matching-code-not-found
Best option is to report the issue via Instagram. However sometimes clearing Instagram cookies helps to resolve that issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526137/my-app-was-rejected-by-instagram-basic-display-api-review-due-to-invalid-reasons

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. I have tried all the solutions available on the SO. But it didn't work.

When I debugged the that Instagram `code` in details, I found that Instagram was providing the `code` something like this after authorization -

`AQAbo7gLQMVRqC4NitrEGSj6tPa8UBREsSYDAL7IZcthASbSKaJANrry3HgQnofJuY4nJx9NTuo_eO4SV8ol4-olk0Y4NzhbXkxTw8G9dBq-T3uZuBzRIVJd61LsYHq15tIeDswI82ri6lt7ngc76eoAAAypgGc3cq9DqayVb7oCpfWZEym6KPH_hJMVaoUOAjN9OT1EEtYuUhmUFgJHHEy66ab9LgHZLXiFxugYBkrdKw#_`

It started working when I removed the ending 2 charaters `#_` from the `code`.
Below is the final `code` that I used to get the `access_token` -

`AQAbo7gLQMVRqC4NitrEGSj6tPa8UBREsSYDAL7IZcthASbSKaJANrry3HgQnofJuY4nJx9NTuo_eO4SV8ol4-olk0Y4NzhbXkxTw8G9dBq-T3uZuBzRIVJd61LsYHq15tIeDswI82ri6lt7ngc76eoAAAypgGc3cq9DqayVb7oCpfWZEym6KPH_hJMVaoUOAjN9OT1EEtYuUhmUFgJHHEy66ab9LgHZLXiFxugYBkrdKw`

This was a simple solution in my case.

I hope this will help people in case they are still facing this issue.

Comment: Can you please look into this question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052304/oauthaccesstokenexception-the-access-token-provided-is-invalid-instagram-new-api